# Display elements from JavaScript object with Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx

https://codepen.io/itsjustcarlos/pen/OJNqWqv

I'm trying display a JSON object in a `<div>` list the json looks like this:

```
const build = {
"brand":[
  {"label":"brand","value":360000022888}
],
"status":[
  {"label":"New","value":"new"},
          {"label":"Open","value":"open"}
 ],
"assigned":[
  {"label":"assigned","value":true}
],
"language":[
  {"label":"English, American","value":"en"},
{"label":"Traditional Chinese","value":"zh-tw"}
],
"priority_level":[
  {"label":"Low","value":"low"}
]
}
```

I'm trying to use Object.entries to cycle through them to display them, I can console.log the values, however they do not render on the page

```
return (
<div>
 {
   Object.entries(build).map((key, value) => { 
   {console.log(key[0])}
  <>
   <div className =''>{key[0]}</div>
   {
      
        value[1]?.map((row, i) => (
        <>
         <div className ='w-3/4 text-sm text-gray-600 bg-gray-900 border-b border-black '> 
            {row.label} 
         </div>
         ))
         </>
       }

 </>
})
} 
</div>
 )
```

Comment: React doesn't render objects.  Iterate over an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.entries()` returns a pair of [key, value]. Use destructuring to get them when mapping.

**Example:**

```
Object.entries(build).map(([key, values]) => ...)
```

```js
const F = React.Fragment // the snippet doesn't support <></>

const Demo = ({ build }) => (
  <div>
    {Object.entries(build)
      .map(([key, values]) => (
        <F>
          <div className="key">{key}</div>
          {values.map(row => (
            <div key={row.label}>{row.label}</div>
          ))}
        </F>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)


const build = {"brand":[{"label":"brand","value":360000022888}],"status":[{"label":"New","value":"new"},{"label":"Open","value":"open"}],"assigned":[{"label":"assigned","value":true}],"language":[{"label":"English, American","value":"en"},{"label":"Traditional Chinese","value":"zh-tw"}],"priority_level":[{"label":"Low","value":"low"}]}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo build={build} />,
  demo
)
```

```css
.key {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the following result on the console you can see it shows all the labels in an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of `string` values:

```js
const build = {"brand":[{"label":"brand","value":360000022888}],"status":[{"label":"New","value":"new"},{"label":"Open","value":"open"}],"assigned":[{"label":"assigned","value":true}],"language":[{"label":"English, American","value":"en"},{"label":"Traditional Chinese","value":"zh-tw"}],"priority_level":[{"label":"Low","value":"low"}]}
const result = Object.entries(build)
                     .map((key, value) => key[0])

console.log(result);
```

Based on this, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to render the **JSX** elements in your component:

```
return <>
  <h1>Labels:</h1>
  <div>
    {
       result.map((label, index) => 
        <div key={index}> 
            {label} 
        </div>
       )
    }
  </div>
</>
```

In the rendered `<div>` elements you can see a `index` attribute and its purpose is to eliminate a warning from React. Read further about [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, what would i do for  key[1]?

Answer (score 0):

used norbitrial as jumping off point and figured it out

```
const values = Object.values(build)
                 .map((key, value) => key)


return (
  <div>

{ result.map((label, index) => 
    <div key={label}> 
        {label} 
    </div>)}
  
  { values.map((label, index) => 
  label.map((entry, i) => 
   <div>{entry.label}</div>
           
           )
  
           
           )}
```